# Top Questions of the Week #13

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 13 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This QotW is now posted:
>   **[Windows 7 Network Awareness: How Windows knows it has an internet connection](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/)**

This question from @nhinkle has sparked quite the interest given that it has only so few views:

**[How does Windows know whether it has internet access or if a Wi-Fi connection requires in-browser authentication?](https://superuser.com/questions/277923/how-does-windows-know-whether-it-has-internet-access-or-if-a-wi-fi-connection-req)**

> In Windows 7, the notification area
>   networking icon will show an error
>   indicator if there is no internet
>   access [image: wifi-err], and the error
>   icon goes away once there is a
>   successful connection to the internet
>   [image: networking normal]. Sometimes, if
>   the WiFi connection requires an
>   in-browser authentication step, like
>   on many guest networks in hotels or
>   universities, then the following
>   pop-up bubble appears, saying as much:
>
> [image: additional log on information may be required, click to open your browser]
>
> **How does Windows know whether or not it has a successful internet
>   connection?**
>  Presumably it is
>   checking some online Microsoft service
>   to see whether it has a successful
>   connection, gets redirected to some
>   other page, or doesn't get any
>   response at all, but I haven't seen
>   anywhere that this process or the
>   services used are documented. Can
>   anybody explain how this works? I
>   would prefer answers that refer to
>   facts, rather than just guessing, but
>   if you have a *really good* guess,
>   then go for it.

And the answers are quite interesting as well!

Comment: I support this and would be willing to blog about it. We have several QOTW still waiting to be written about though, so it might be a while until this one gets written.